# Kunneth theorem for Hom

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $C_*$ and $D_*$ be chain complexes of vector spaces over a field $k$. The classical Kunneth theorem states that the homology of the  complex $Tot(C_* \otimes D_*)$ is isomorphic to $H_*(C) \otimes H_*(D)$.

I am interested in a similar statement for the hom functor. Namely, it is also true that
$H^*(\hom(C_*,D_*)) \cong \hom(H_*(C), H_*(D))$

If so, is there a reference for this fact?

Comment: How do you define $\text{hom}(H_*(C),H_*(D))$? And you make $\text{hom}(C_*,D_*)$ into a cochain complex by letting differential $\delta$ be precomposition with $\partial_C$? I.e a degree $i$ map $f: C_* \rightarrow D_*$ gets taken to the degree $i+1$ map $f \circ \partial_C$?

Comment: I am considering the hom complex as in the following sense. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+hom+of+chain+complexes

Comment: Ok, I see. But in your post you are taking the cohomology of the chain complex $\text{hom}(C,D)$ what does that mean? You can only take the cohomology of a cochain complex.

Comment: If you define the double complex $C_{i,j}=\text{hom}(C_{-i},D_j)$ then your associated total complex $\textbf{Tot}(C)=\text{hom}(C_*,D_*)$. From here you can maybe use the spectral sequence for a double complex to calculate the homology.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spectral+sequence+of+a+double+complex

Comment: I think since we are consider objects over a field, this spectral sequence has $E_2$ term given by $\hom(H_*(C), H_*(D))$. The problem is again argue why it degenerates at the $E_2$-term